# How can I ask for credentials but assume Domain?

Tags: powershell, winforms, user-interface

I have a script to make sure needed PS modules are installed and get the latest version of all files needed for running a script. What I have does work but I would rather it "assume" the domain instead of having to have the domain in the username field. having to pre-populate the username field is a nuisanse to the users.I need it to ask for network credentials not local credentials.

```
Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);'

[VOID] [Console.Window]::ShowWindow([Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow(), 0)
<# 
.NAME
    Template
#>

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400,400)
$Form.text                       = "ToolBox Updater"
$Form.StartPosition              = "CenterScreen"
$Form.TopMost                    = $true
$Form.Width                      = 520
$Form.Height                     = 180


$Label                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.text                     = "Click Start to Update Application and Install Required Modules"
$Label.AutoSize                 = $true
$Label.width                    = 25
$Label.height                   = 10
$Label.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(16,16)
$Label.Font                     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$jobScript =
{
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}

function LoadStuff {
   $ProgressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
    $ProgressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(16, 45)
    $ProgressBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(460, 20)
    $ProgressBar.Style = "Marquee"
    $ProgressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 20
    
    $Form.Controls.Add($ProgressBar);

    $Label.Font = $procFont
    #$Label.ForeColor = 'red'
    $Label.Text = "Processing ..."
    $ProgressBar.visible

    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $jobScript
    do { [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents() } until ($job.State -eq "Completed")
    Remove-Job -Job $job -Force


    $Label.Text = "Modules Successfully Loaded"
    $ProgressBar.Hide()
    $StartButton.Hide()
    $EndButton.Visible

    try {
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    #Write-Host "Module exists"
} 
catch {
    Install-Module -Name ActiveDirectory
    }
try {
    Import-Module AzureAD
    Write-Host "Module exists"
} 
catch {
    Install-Module -Name AzureAD
}

try {
    Import-Module MSOnline
    #Write-Host "Module exists"
} 
catch {
    Install-Module -Name MSOnline

  
}}

$StartButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$StartButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(350, 90)
$StartButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60, 25)
$StartButton.Text = "Start"
$StartButton.height = 40
#$StartButton.BackColor = 'red'
#$StartButton.ForeColor = 'white'
$StartButton.Add_click( { LoadStuff });

$EndButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$EndButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(350, 90)
$EndButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(60, 25)
$EndButton.Text = "OK"
$EndButton.height = 40
#$EndButton.BackColor = 'red'
#$EndButton.ForeColor = 'white'
$EndButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$EndButton.Add_click( { otbx })


$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Label,$ProgressBar,$Button1,$StartButton,$EndButton))

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {


}

function otbx {
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath '\\ServerName\Topfolder\Subfolder\newversion.zip' -DestinationPath C:\local Folder -Force
$Form.Close()
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Start-Process -FilePath Powershell "C:\Local Folder\Main script.ps1" -Credential Domain\
}


[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: It is just a string so you can combine : "domain"+ "username"

Comment: all we see is a call to 'Main Script.ps1' where you specify the parameter `-Credential Domain\ ` but we have no idea how the user is being prompted, that's not shown. Please show the relevant script portion.

Comment: "-Credential Domain\" prompts the user for username and password in a windows dialog, with the domain name\ pre-populated in the username field. I am looking to have it already know the domain name.

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: it is completely reproducable by running the script sa posted. you will get errors in ISE due to fake path names. but the dialog will come up. what I am trying to do is have the username field empty but still pass the domain with the username and password

Comment: Minimal code: Start-Process -FilePath Powershell "C:\Local Folder\Main script.ps1" -Credential Domain\ I need it to "not" populate the domain name in the username field. But I need it to pass the domain credentials not local credentials to the script it is opening. I dont know how to make it any more simple than that.

Comment: you will have to create an additional field that will be automatically filled in on domen\user with the ability to edit and remember. Also add a field for the password c *****. Next, $cred = New-Object System is standard.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $pwd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got now. I changed the function to get the current user and add -ADM to the end

```
$usr = (Get-WmiObject  –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName).Username
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath '\\ServerName\FolderName\SubfolderName\Current_Version_Main_Script.zip' -DestinationPath C:\Local_Folder -Force
$Form.Close()
Start-Process -FilePath Powershell "C:\folder\Main_script.ps1" -Credential $usr-ADM
```